# YQ Error When Attempting to Download Kubeflow Management Cluster Blueprint on GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, yaml, kubeflow, yq

I'm fairly new to Kubeflow and am having difficulty following the [instructions](https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/gke/deploy/) for deploying it on GCP. After getting through the first two sections of the deployment process, I get stuck at "[Management Cluster Setup](https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/gke/deploy/management-setup/#setting-up-a-management-cluster)" when asked to use the Makefile to download the Kubeflow Management Cluster Blueprint from GitHub.

From within the management directory (specified as the env var $MGMT_DIR as per instructions), I run the `make get-pkg` command to run the appropriate Makefile instructions. On execution, I receive these error messages:

```
usage: yq [-h] [--yaml-output] [--yaml-roundtrip] [--width WIDTH]
          [--indentless-lists] [--in-place] [--version]
          [jq_filter] [files [files ...]]
yq: error: argument files: can't open 'openAPI.definitions."io.k8s.cli.setters.name".x-k8s-cli.setter.value': [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'openAPI.defin
itions."io.k8s.cli.setters.name".x-k8s-cli.setter.value'
usage: yq [-h] [--yaml-output] [--yaml-roundtrip] [--width WIDTH]
          [--indentless-lists] [--in-place] [--version]
          [jq_filter] [files [files ...]]
yq: error: argument files: can't open 'openAPI.definitions."io.k8s.cli.setters.location".x-k8s-cli.setter.value': [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'openAPI.d
efinitions."io.k8s.cli.setters.location".x-k8s-cli.setter.value'
usage: yq [-h] [--yaml-output] [--yaml-roundtrip] [--width WIDTH]
          [--indentless-lists] [--in-place] [--version]
          [jq_filter] [files [files ...]]
yq: error: argument files: can't open 'openAPI.definitions."io.k8s.cli.setters.gcloud.core.project".x-k8s-cli.setter.value': [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
 'openAPI.definitions."io.k8s.cli.setters.gcloud.core.project".x-k8s-cli.setter.value'
usage: yq [-h] [--yaml-output] [--yaml-roundtrip] [--width WIDTH]
          [--indentless-lists] [--in-place] [--version]
          [jq_filter] [files [files ...]]
yq: error: argument files: can't open 'openAPI.definitions."io.k8s.cli.setters.name".x-k8s-cli.setter.value': [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'openAPI.defin
itions."io.k8s.cli.setters.name".x-k8s-cli.setter.value'
mkdir -p  ./upstream
usage: yq [-h] [--yaml-output] [--yaml-roundtrip] [--width WIDTH]
          [--indentless-lists] [--in-place] [--version]
          [jq_filter] [files [files ...]]
yq: error: argument files: can't open 'openAPI.definitions."io.k8s.cli.setters.name".x-k8s-cli.setter.value': [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'openAPI.defin
itions."io.k8s.cli.setters.name".x-k8s-cli.setter.value'
kpt pkg get https://github.com/kubeflow/gcp-blueprints.git/packages/management@v1.2.0 ./upstream/management
fetching package /packages/management from https://github.com/kubeflow/gcp-blueprints to upstream/management
```

It looks like each message is referencing a different "`.setters.`" API which seems to reference the environmental variables I created earlier. I looked at the GitHub repo for "[kubeflow/gcp-blueprints/management](https://github.com/kubeflow/gcp-blueprints/tree/master/management)" and while I'm not sure it makes a difference, the instructions on the GitHub page aren't the same exactly as the Kubeflow installation guide. Mostly this section:

**Kubeflow Instructions:**

```
kpt cfg set -R . name "${MGMT_NAME}"
kpt cfg set -R . gcloud.core.project "${MGMT_PROJECT}"
kpt cfg set -R . location "${LOCATION}"
```

**GitHub Instructions:**

```
kpt cfg set -R . name ${NAME}
kpt cfg set -R . gcloud.core.project ${PROJECT}
kpt cfg set -R . location ${LOCATION}
```

Is there something in the Makefile that is incorrect or depreciated from a previous Kubeflow version?

Comment: Check this [post](https://github.com/kubeflow/website/issues/2419) from the Kubeflow issues website and see if it will work on your end.

Comment: What is the question about `yq` for this? doesn't seem to be related IMO

Comment: @AlexG The error mentioned in your link is not really the same as what I'm seeing, but it could still have something to do with the version of `yq`. I checked the version installed on my VM and it's v2.1.

Comment: Does changing the yq version have any effects?

Answer (score 1):

There are two different implementations of `yq`:

- [yq](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/) (written in Go)
- [yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq) (written in Python)

The syntax is very similar but not identical and each version has its own parameters.
The error indicates that the wrong implementation is being used.